# Python equivalent for for R matrix operation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pandas

What is the Python/Numpy/Pandas equivalent for the R code:

```
for (i in 1:n) m1[i,] <- colSums(m2[i,]*m3)
```

Many thanks!!

Comment: What does that do in R? I don't know very much R, but if you explain the functionality, I might be able to give you something in python that does what you need

Comment: Also, what are m1, m2, and m3? Matrices of shape (i x 1), (i x 1), and (1 x i), respectively?

Comment: What is `m3`? Can you provide the shapes of these matrices?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: From your question, it appears like you want to iterate over every row of `m2`, multiply it with matrix `m3` elementwise and the store the column sums of those matrices in corresponding rows of `m1`. So I am assuming these dimensions: `m1: (n, m), m2: (n, m), m3: (n1, m)`. In general, `n1 != n` but the column dimension `m` is same for all.

In numpy

```
m1 = numpy.matrix(map(lambda a: (a * m3).sum(axis=0), m2))
```

This one line takes every row of `m2`, multiplies it by `m3` (elementswise, not matrix-matrix multiplication, since your original R code has a `*`) and then takes colsums by passing `axis=0` to `sum`. Here `m1, m2, m3` are standard numpy arrays or matrices.

In pandas, you can use `apply` to do similar thing

```
m1 = m2.apply(lambda a: (a * m3).sum(axis=0))
```